# Custom Scala implementation of generic Future.sequence

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make sure I understand how to write clean and robust idiomatic Scala, so I wrote a custom generic implementation `sequence` of type `A[B[C]] => B[A[C]]` (instead of `TraversableOnce[Future[A]] => Future[TraversableOnce[A]]` -- I know something like this exists in scalaz).

Is the following code a reasonable and idiomatic way of writing `sequence`? Are there existing traits in the core Scala library that would be easy to substitute for `Liftable`, `Monoid`, and `Traversable` that would keep this implementation of `sequence` relatively intact? What are the most significant improvements that can be made to this code?

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.Future
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.util.Success
import scala.util.Failure

object TestMain {

  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext
    .fromExecutorService(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)

  trait Liftable[A[_], B[_]] {
    def lift[C](bc: B[C]): B[A[C]]
  }

  trait Monoid[A] {
    def mappend(a1: A, a2: A): A
    def mzero: A
  }

  trait Traversable[T[_]] {
    def head[A](t: T[A]): Option[A]
    def next[A](t: T[A]): T[A]
  }

  implicit val listOfFutureLiftable = new Liftable[List, Future] {
    def lift[C](fc: Future[C]) = fc.map(c => List(c))
  }

  implicit def listMonoid[A] = new Monoid[List[A]] {
    def mappend(a1: List[A], a2: List[A]) = a1 ++ a2
    def mzero = Nil
  }

  implicit def futureMonoid[A: Monoid] = new Monoid[Future[A]] {
    def mappend(a1: Future[A], a2: Future[A]) = {
      for {
        v1 <- a1
        v2 <- a2
      } yield implicitly[Monoid[A]].mappend(v1, v2)
    }
    def mzero = Future.successful(implicitly[Monoid[A]].mzero)
  }

  implicit val listTraversable = new Traversable[List] {
    def head[A](l: List[A]) = l match {
      case Nil => None
      case x :: _ => Some(x)
    }

    def next[A](l: List[A]) = l.tail
  }

  def sequence[A[_], B[_], C](lf: A[B[C]])(
    implicit ta: Traversable[A],
    lab: Liftable[A, B],
    mb: Monoid[B[A[C]]]): B[A[C]] = {
    val obc: Option[B[C]] = ta.head(lf)
    obc match {
      case Some(bc) => {
        val first: B[A[C]] = lab.lift(bc)
        val tail: A[B[C]] = ta.next(lf)
        val rest: B[A[C]] = sequence(tail)
        mb.mappend(first, rest)
      }
      case None => mb.mzero
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val lfi: List[Future[Int]] = List(Future(1), Future(2))
    val fli: Future[List[Int]] = sequence(lfi)
    fli andThen {
      case Success(li) => println(li)
      case Failure(e) => println("fail: " + e)
    } andThen {
      case _ => ec.shutdown
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Core Scala lacks the abstractions you are looking for (it contains only function types in this regard).